# Why DBAN cannot erase data on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, security, secure-erase

As stated in DBAN website, DBAN, which using "DoD 5220.22-M", is not recommended for wiping SSD drives since DBAN was designed for HDD. As I understand, it is because SSD has over provisioning and data stored in this space cannot be overwrite. But my IT friend told me that no data will be stored in over provisioning space, this space just for data relocation when garbage collection.

So can DBAN permanently and completely erase stored data on SSDs and Why?

Comment: In general, wiping techniques for hard drives are not useful for SSDs.

Comment: Look up wear leveling for SSDs for a more complete explanation.   Some SSDs support a "secure wipe" command.

Comment: do you mean " ATA enhanced secure erase" command? or should I use hdparm sanitize-block-erase or sanitize-crypto-scramble?

Comment: The methods of erasure available depend on SSD support.  The reality though is that if the command works your data is irretrievably deleted regardless of which method you pick - https://tinyapps.org/docs/ata_sanitize_hdparm.html

Answer (score 3):

Your IT friend is not fully correct.  Data is absolutely stored in the overprovisioning space and why DBAN likely can't completely erase SSD's.

The garbage in garbage collection is not actual garbage, its still fragments of your data - possibly deleted data, or data that has been duplicated/moved/changed, but nonetheless your data.

Also, cells wear out with writes and the SSD starts using the overprovisioned area. While the disk presents as an SATA disk (in the case of SATA SSD's) the actual mapping of data on the disk does not match what the disk tells the OS - effectively abstracting and hiding data from the PC.  There is no way for DBAN to access this data let alone rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks!! so If I use enhanced secure erase ATA command, can the data stored in overprovisioning be erased? as I want to buy this tool [link](https://diskdeleter.com//diskdeleter-provides-16-types-of-the-most-critical-data-erasing-methods/) to replace DBAN. it stated that it can erases mapping tables and memory cells, but doesn't mention whether overprovisioning data can also erase.

Comment: If your disk supports it, Enhanced secure erase will have the same effect as erasing everything including overpartitioned data. (In reality it doesnt erase your data.  How it works is when your data is stored it uses encryption - at the disk level - and the enhanced secure erase deletes the key known only to the drive.)  It works a lot like Windows bitlocker - indeed it sometimes integrates with bitlocker.

Comment: Im not sure how much that software costs or why you would use it though. There are plenty of free ways to do exactly this for free as the hard work is done in hardware - https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/secure-erase-ssd-or-hard-drive